# Amber lights on packet tracer

Tags: packet-tracer

Im doing a project and need to show a sample of it to my colleagues asap.
So I worked on it with packet tracer,but some of the link lights are showing amber(orange).
I checked the corresponding line protocols and interfaces, and they are up. But link lights are orange.
Anyone got an idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure about packet tracer, but on real switches, it means the port is not forwarding traffic (usually due to spanning tree).

Comment: Okay. So how do we fix that Ron?

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more information: a simple diagram of your network along with the device configurations.

Comment: there you go ron

Comment: If you can, please put the image back, so others can learn from your question.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the diagram, it looks like spanning tree has blocked the amber ports.  That's expected behavior.  You might want to set the priorities to adjust which ports get blocked.